# Tracking multiple different URL clicks as conversions in Google Adwords

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

The goal is to track multiple different URL clicks as conversions in Google Adwords.

If I install only one link click tracking script everything works perfect. If I install 2 or more only 1 will work at a time and the others fail.

Inside of the head section I am using this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function trackConv(google_conversion_id, google_conversion_label) {
        var image = new Image(1, 1); 
        image.src = "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/" +     google_conversion_id + "/?label=" + google_conversion_label;  
    }
 </script>
```

Just after the beginning body tag I am using this code to track clicks on the Facebook URL:

```
    <!-- Google Code for Facebook Click Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = 945293991;
    w.google_conversion_label = "GGLkCKb7uWEQp5XgwgM";
    w.google_conversion_value = 2.00;
    w.google_conversion_currency = "USD";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

If I stop here it works fine. If I go and add another block like below to track Twitter then it breaks:

```
    <!-- Google Code for Twitter Click Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = 945293991;
    w.google_conversion_label = "6NygCKTOv2QQp5XgwgM";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

Where the actual URL link occurs inside the body I am using code like this:

```
<a onclick="trackConv(945293991, 'GGLkCKb7uWEQp5XgwgM');" href="https://www.facebook.com/the-foo-bar-fb-page-url" target="_blank" rel="attachment wp-att-864">AN ICON HERE</a>

<a onclick="trackConv(945293991, '6NygCKTOv2QQp5XgwgM');" href="https://twitter.com/the-foo-bar-tw-page-url" target="_blank" rel="attachment wp-att-862">AN ICON HERE</a>
```

What I tried to do to fix it:

I tried only using the code shown below one time - before all of the Google Adwords code and again after all of it and regardless of how many times I use the script or where I place it if I try to have more than one tag instance it breaks:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking outbound clicks as goals in Google Analytics can be achieved a few different ways.

1. [AutoTrack.js](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2016/02/introducing-autotrack-for-analyticsjs.html) - This new feature is the simplest way.
2. [Google Tag Manager Events](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?rd=1)
3. Manually tagging links with on_click

The 3rd option requires you to insert a single script in the page header, but outside the standard Google analytics script.

```
    <script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

Once you have that script installed then you can manually tag each link you want to track as such:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

[Read more here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en#GA)

After you have done that you can follow the steps below to then track those events as goals in Google Analytics.

There is an easier way to track multiple URL's as conversions in Adwords.

You should link your Adwords account with your Google Analytics account and then create a [Destination Goal](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375435?hl=en&authuser=0) for each URL you want to track as a conversion.

Once you have the destination goals configured and tracking in Google Analytics you can then use the [automatic import feature in Adwords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375435?hl=en&authuser=0) to import those conversions and Adwords will only show conversions that came from Adwords clicks.

Comment: When trying to implement your suggestion it appears that the destination goal for a given URL must be within the site and cannot be an external page. For example Google gives this example - For example, use My Screen for an app and **/thankyou.html** instead of **www.example.com/thankyou.html** for a web page. It appears that the destination url would be required to be within the original domain.